# Loading failed for the <script> require.js

Tags: magento2

I am trying to deploy the static content but in frontend and backend require js is not being loaded see error :

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://example.com/dev/pub/static/version1525976399/frontend/Sm/market/en_GB/requirejs/require.js”.
dev:20
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://example.com/dev/pub/static/version1525976399/frontend/Sm/market/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js”.
dev:21
TypeError: require.config is not a function[Learn More]
```

I have tried following command :

```
php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile
For Deployment:
php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

But it's not helped. How to resolved it ?

Comment: I think that your js is not well included via `requirejs`, Try to clean the `pub/static` content then run : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` if it doesn't work, please post you code to how you included your js !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using developer or default mode then try to use:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

This will happen if you clear the pub/static folder instead of pub/static/frontend. You'll lose the .htaccess in there which messes things up royally! Restore pub/static/.htaccess from your local files/backup and it'll correct.

Comment: This is the most useful answer and should be the accepted one. Worked!

Comment: Does .htaccess needs be present in the directory if I am using nginx?

Answer (score 2):

Run below command and check

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```